# False update on all opportunity in production

Tags: apex

Hi i have to do false update on all opportunities in production.
What should be best way to do that.Can i do that with apex script.

Something like 
List opp=[select id from opportunites];
update opp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have a batch class I've deployed to production for this very purpose:

```
public class BatchUpdate implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    String query;
    public BatchUpdate(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, SObject[] records) {
        update records;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Once deployed, you can then run a query against any object:

```
Database.executeBatch(new BatchUpdate('select id from opportunity'));
```

I actually have a more advanced one that allows custom execute methods, but you'll find that this class comes in handy probably every second project or so.

Comment: Ossum sfdcfox..But in production we cannot have this batch right now.Will definetly suggest client next time..Could you please suggest any other apporox apart from fetching all ids from dataloader..For one time false update on opportunites

Comment: @ArunSharma Without using code or some sort of tool, you can't reliably update more than 10k records directly through Apex Code. If it's less than 10k records, `update [select id from opportunity];` would work. Beyond that, your transaction will simply be too large, and you'll need to use a tool like the Data Loader or code like I've suggested.

Comment: Thanks I will add this class in utility class in our production next time,for false update on any object :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that way, but if you have more than 10000 records, it will give you an error.

The alternative is, you can use apex data loader or Workbench to do the update.
Export all records to excel and use that to update.